# Insert php array value into database

Tags: php, mysqli

I am working on this hashtag system. am trying to get the hashtag words into the database in a new row. for every hashtag word i need it to insert into a new row.
Below is my php line of code...

```
$string = filter_var("#hello #world", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
preg_match_all('/(?<!\w)#\w+/', $string, $matches);

foreach ($matches as $key => $value) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO hash_tag (tagged_word) VALUES (?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $value);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

doing it this way it doesnt insert anything into the database but when i replace the `$value` to `$value[0]`, it input the first which is `#hello`.

I want to input both `#hello` and `#world` into the database as a new row.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the foreach loop from:

```
foreach ($matches as $key => $value) {
```

To

```
foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $value) {
```

Because, `$matches` is a multi-dimensional array and we are trying to access its 0th and 1st elements, which are again arrays not strings.

If we try to access first sub-array of `$matches`, it will work perfectly.

So, the final code is:

```
<?php
$string = filter_var("#hello #world", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
preg_match_all('/(?<!\w)#\w+/', $string, $matches);

if (isset($matches[0]) && ! empty($matches[0])) {
    foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $value) {
        //echo '<pre>';print_r($key);echo '</pre>';
        //echo '<pre>';print_r($value);echo '</pre>';
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO hash_tag (tagged_word) VALUES (?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $value);
    $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```